# How to retrieve json response without a root object in c#

Tags: c#, json

I have following json string:

```
{
    Syangja : {},
    Tulsipur : {},
    Pokhara : {},
    Butwal : {},
    Madhumalla : {},
    Dhangadhi : {},
    Siddharthanagar(Bhairahawa) : {},
    Banepa : {},
    Bharatpur : {},
    Dharan : {},
    Lalitpur : {},
    Biratnagar : {},
    Dang : {},
    Kathmandu : {
        5 star : {
            median : "141.72",
            lowest : "96.54",
            value : "141.72"
        },
        1 star : {
            median : "36.33",
            lowest : "36.33",
            value : "36.33"
        },
        4 star : {
            median : "53.10",
            lowest : "22.12",
            value : "53.10"
        },
        2 star : {
            median : "21.00",
            lowest : "20.33",
            value : "21.00"
        },
        3 star : {
            median : "25.00",
            lowest : "20.11",
            value : "25.00"
        }
    },
    Bajhang : {},
    Janakpur : {},
    Birganj : {}
}
```

I want to retrieve this at once. how can I do that.I'm stuck with this because this does not has a root object and other thing is object names are different each time.so how to get these cities to separate arrays in  C#. that means `kathmandu` city data to one array, and `Syangja` city data to one array. Is it possible? If it is possible, how can I do that?

Comment: You JSON is not valid to begin with.

Comment: @Nasreddine, you could mention the error too. @Bill if you add `"` to names your first issue will be solved. e.g. change `2 star` to `"2 star"` and as pedro mentioned `Siddharthanagar(Bhairahawa)` to `"Siddharthanagar(Bhairahawa)"`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the JSON example you provided isn't valid. The **Siddharthanagar (Bhairahawa): { },** will not parse as valid JSON due to the parenthesis.

Having said that, ANY object that you have pegged as [Serializable] will map to JSON if you for example using NewtonSoft to deserialize it:

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.Deserialize<MyObject>(yourJsonString);
```

As long as the JSON serializer can map any field, then you're golden.

Comment: this is the response from the web service

Comment: Well, it doesen't parse as JSON, you can try it here (among a ton of online json parsers) http://jsonlint.com/